# Adding trisector vectors on an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

> In the equilateral triangle ABC with the length of one side 3, there are $P,Q \in BC$ such that $BP=PQ=QC$. If $G$ is the weight center of the triangle what is the length of $\vec{GP}+\vec{GQ}$:
>
>  
> A: $\sqrt{3}$
>
>  
> B: $2\sqrt{3}$
>
>  
> C: $\frac{ \sqrt{3}}{2}$
>
>  
> D: $\frac {2\sqrt{3}}{3}$
>
>  
> E: $\frac{1}{3}$

I made a sketch and got that $\frac{MQ}{MC}=\frac{MG}{AG}=\frac{1}{2}$ so from the Thales theorem $ GQ\parallel AC$ and also $PG \parallel AB$ but I do not know what to do from here.

Comment: In the firs sentence, point G looks to be an error for point Q ?

Comment: @JeanMarie corrected that one, but I couldn't work out what $M$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$, [the centroid, is on every median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_triangle), $\frac 13$ up from the base. So $|GP|=|GQ|=3\cdot\frac 23\cdot \frac 12 = 1$. From your parallel observations, we know that the angle between $\vec{GP}$ and $\vec{GQ}$ is $60^\circ$ so they are both at $30^\circ$ from the resultant $\vec{GP}+\vec{GQ}$. We can calculate this geometrically as twice the altitude of an equilateral with side length $1$, giving $|\vec{GP}+\vec{GQ}| = \sqrt{3\,}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!